# convert xml response to JSON sencha touch 2

Tags: xml, json, sencha-touch-2

I have recently started a project in Sencha touch with existing Web-services. Being very new to the technology, I am facing certain issues in accomplishing some functionality.

Problem I have to load a content xml nested in a json response  and the request goes like:

```
              load: function(me, records, successful, operation, eOpts) {
            Ext.data.JsonP.request({
                url: 'My-url-site',
                params: {
                    format: 'jsonp'
                },
                success: function(result) {
                   var xml = result.configuration; 
                    var oParser = new DOMParser();
                    var data = oParser.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
                    console.log(data );  // i get a pure xml content ( <?xml version="1.0"?>.....) here but i need to save it into a file .xml to use it in a store , or to parse the string using some function in sencha touch  i guess 
                }
            });
           }
```

My reponse : (a json file with xml content)

```
 {"status":"ok","configuration":"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<application id=\"1\"    name=\"Kat\" color=\"#1a7892\" scdcolor=\"#666666\" language_id=\"ca\">
 <modules>
  <module id=\"32\" type=\"Home\"><application_params><param name=\"is_active\"    value=\"1\"\/><param name=\"order\" value=\"0\"\/><param name=\"menu_icon\" value=\"ico_home\"\/><param name=\"menu_text\" value=\"Home+CA\"\/><param   name=\"headlines\" value=\"1\"\/><\/application_params>
 <\/module>
 <module><\/module>
<module><\/module>
 <module><\/module>
  <\/modules>
 <\/application>\n"}
```

Ext.encode(xml) doesn't work , is there a fonction to convert xml string to json ? or to save my string to a file .xml in order to use it locally with a store ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am missing something, if all you need to do is load your data you can define the store with an xml proxy which will populate your models automatically.

See [Ext.data.proxy.Proxy - type xml](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Proxy-cfg-reader)

Edit:

You could try creating a [convert function](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-convert) for your field.
In your model:

```
fields : [{
    name : 'configuration',
    convert : function(value, record) {
        // I'm not sure about this, I have never used a reader in this way but it looks possible.

        var reader = new Ext.data.reader.Reader({
            // See [config][3]
        });

        reader.read();
        // or
        reader.readReacord();

        // Then set your records with the data from the 
    }
}]
```

Again, this is not something I have used but from the documentation it looks promising.

Let me know if you run into any snags.

Comment: Yikes, do you have any control over that? You would be much better in my opinion using one or the other.

Comment: i have just one 'config' it contains xml , its not enough clear for me , can u plese give a complete example ?

Comment: Sencha has a powerful MVC structure that you should really stick to. Videos to help understand: [MVC Video pt 1](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/video/mvc-part-1). Pay attention to the Stores Section as well as the [Store class](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store).

Also, you will find yourself better off by using the [Ext.data.reader.Reader class](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader) Sencha has packaged for you rather than using a DOMParser().